# Manipulating ASP.NET response headers not working

Tags: asp.net, http-headers

I want to allow cashing for a specific ajax request.
Currently the response does not allow this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-SLPROMOTION: DEBUG
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcS2F5WmFuZGVyXERvY3VtZW50c1xWaXN1YWwgU3R1ZGlvIDIwMTVcUHJvamVjdHNcc3BvcnRsb29wXHRvb3R3b29cQWNjb3VudFxJc1RyYWluZXI=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SDL-VERSION: 1.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 13:18:04 GMT
Content-Length: 51
```

So I set the headers:

```
  public JsonResult MyFunction()
        {          
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("cache-control");
            HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("cache-control", "public");
...}
```

but the response still contains:

```
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
```

Could this be caused by a global setting or what is the trick here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately the browser still cashes the request after a sign out of the user... How can deal with this?